# GraphQL / Strapi - Can not filter by string field

Tags: graphql, strapi

According to the GraphQL docs, it should be as simple as:

```
query Link($slug: String) {
      link(slug: $slug) {
        slug
      }
    }
```

But I am getting *Error: unknown field slug*
I have searched other answers and other docs, and tried the following queries as well:

*"Unknown argument "where" on field "link" of type "Query".*

```
query Link($slug: String) {
  link(where: {slug: $slug}) {
    slug
  }
}
```

*Error: Unknown argument "where" on field "link" of type "Query".*

```
{ 
  link: link(where: { slug: "a" }) {
    slug
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Strapi v4, I think they removed `where`. So, I make it work with `filters`.

```
query Links($id: String) {
    links(filters: { slug: {eq: $id}}) {
      data{
         attributes{
            slug,
            title
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally after much more examining the docs, I was able to get the following query to work:

```
query Links($id: String) {
    links(where: { slug: $id }) {
      slug
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey, how did you make it work? i have the same issue. unknown argument where
```
query getArticleBySlug($id: String) {
  articles(where: { slug: $id }) {
    slug
  }
}
```

Comment: hey sorry been a super long time, but I'm guessing the above thing worked somehow...